How to create a data from a function over a course of 500 generations and then plot the data
I am trying create y-values using this formulae over the course of 500 generations.
#3a Answer: Initial population of hare
delta_H <- function(r1,Hn,Ln,d1)
  return(r1*Hn*(1-(Ln/d1)))
r1 <- 0.05
Hn <- 300000 
Ln <- 1500
d1 <- 1.5e+07
delta_H(r1,Hn,Ln,d1)

#3b Answer: Initial population of lynx
delta_L <- function(r2,Hn,Ln,d2)
  return(r2*Ln*(1-(Hn/d2)))
r2 <- -0.06
Hn <- 300000 
Ln <- 1500
d2 <- -1.8e+07
delta_L(r2,Hn,Ln,d2)

I have tried the following but it is not giving me my expected cycle graph
initial_hare_population <- 300000
Hn <- initial_hare_population
Hn <- 300000
initial_lynx_population <- 1500
Ln <- initial_lynx_population
Ln <- 1500
pop_Hn <- c(300000)
pop_Ln <- c(1500)
generations <- seq(0,500)
for (generation in generations) {
  delta_Hn <- delta_H(r1,Hn,Ln,d1)
  delta_Ln <- delta_L(r2,Hn,Ln,d2)
  Hn <- Hn+delta_Hn
  Ln <- Ln+delta_Ln
  pop_Hn <- append(pop_Hn,c(Hn))
  pop_Ln <- append(pop_Ln,c(Ln))
}
df <- data.frame(pop_Hn, pop_Ln, generations)
plot(df$generations,pop_Hn, xlab="Generation of Hares", ylab="Hare population")
plot(df$generations, pop_Ln, xlab="Generation of Lynx", ylab="Lynx population")

I have also tried this
curve(delta_H(r1,Hn,Ln,d1), from = 0, to = 500, n = 500, 
      xlab = "Generation of Hare", ylab = "Population of Hare", 
      main = "Change in Hare population over 500 generations")

But R gave the following error message about it.
Error in curve(delta_H(r1, Hn, Ln, d1), from = 0, to = 500, n = 500, xlab = "Generation of Hare",  : 
  'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'

So, how can I create a graph that shows the population change over the course of 500 generations using the above formulae in R?

generations is a vector of length 501 running from 0 to 500, while pop_Hn/pop_Ln are each vectors 502 long, since they have an initial value and then are processed once for each element of generations

When I run this, the Lynx population becomes less than 1 about 70 generations in, and becomes less than 0.000000000etc0001 in the mid 100s, but then explodes to a gajillion around generation 200. You probably need to make there be an integer number of creatures. df <- data.frame(pop_Hn = pop_Hn[2:502], pop_Ln = pop_Ln[2:502], generations) ggplot(df, aes(x = generations)) +   geom_line(aes(y = pop_Ln, color = "Lynx")) +   geom_line(aes(y = pop_Hn/1E7, color = "Hare")) +   coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1E3))

@JonSpring, does this mean that I have to change my sequence to 498?

I think a few ways to handle this, but one could be to use generations = seq(2,500), run your loop, then generations = c(1, generations) so that every vector is 500 long.

@JonSpring, I tried the code you provided, thank you. It gave me a graph but that is not my expected graph. So, maybe, my calculations are faulty. I will also try your last suggestion. Thank you for your help

Using r2 -0.06 and Hn 3E5 and d2 -1.8E7, I see the Lynx population decline (ie negative delta_L) even when there are only a handful of them but loads of hares, which is unexpected. I'd take another look at the formula. Other formulations of this I have seen (like this: https://jckantor.github.io/CBE30338/02.05-Hare-and-Lynx-Population-Dynamics.html) separately combine the effect of a birth rate  with the effect of a death rate; it seems unusual that they should be multiplied together.

Awesome. Thank you @JonSpring. My death rate value was wrong so that's why the data was off. I redid the calculation and when r=-0.06, d2 = Hn; and when r=0.05, d1 = Ln. Using these values, my original code worked just fine. Thanks again
